# mapping over nested tibbles and run regressions

Tags: r

I have some data which looks similar to the following:

Data:

```
rank_A <- sample(x = 1:5, size  = 100, replace = TRUE)
rank_B <- sample(x = 1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

Y_A <- rnorm(n = 100)
Y_B <- rnorm(n = 100)

X <- rnorm(n = 100)

df <- data.frame(rank_A, rank_B, Y_A, Y_B, X)
```

Which looks like:

```
> tibble(df)
# A tibble: 100 x 1
   df$rank_A $rank_B   $Y_A   $Y_B      $X
       <int>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         5       1  0.128 -0.833  1.15  
 2         2       1  0.165  0.325  0.225 
 3         1       3  0.525 -0.632  0.390 
 4         5       3 -1.32   0.718 -0.377 
 5         4       2 -0.900 -0.364 -0.259 
 6         5       3 -1.17   0.556 -0.0702
 7         4       1 -0.560 -1.66  -1.64  
 8         5       1 -2.01  -0.898  0.306 
 9         1       1 -2.56   0.693  1.34  
10         4       2  0.338 -0.733 -0.481 
# ... with 90 more rows
```

So I have two rank columns and a corresponding `Y` for each rank. `A` and `B` here are just two categories. I want to run two regressions both on `Y_A` and `Y_B` both regressed on `X`. I have the following code which works for `rank_A`.

```
df_regs <- df %>%
  group_by(rank_A) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    Reg_A = map(data,
                ~lm(Y_A ~ X,
                    data = .)
                ),
    Reg_A_summary = map(Reg_A,
                        ~summary(.)
                        )
    )


df_regs$Reg_A_summary
```

I would like to construct it such that I do not have to write a new piece of code for `rank_B`. I have many different regressions (different `X` variables I will give to each `Y_A` and `Y_B`). I thought about doing something like the following (which doesn't work).

```
df %>%
  mutate(Class_A = group_by(rank_A) %>%
           nest() %>%
           mutate(
             Reg_A = map(data,
                         ~lm(Y_a ~ X,
                             data = .)
                         )
             ),
         Class_B = group_by(rank_B) %>%
           nest() %>%
           mutate(
             Reg_B = map(data,
                         ~lm(Y_b ~ X,
                             data = .)
                         )
             )
         )
```

If you know of a cleaner method, please also let me know your thoughts as I will have many regressions.

Comment: I think here you need `cbind`  `lm(cbind(Y_A, Y_B) ~ X, df)` i.e. `df %>% group_by(rank_A) %>% nest %>% mutate(Reg = map(data, ~ lm(cbind(Y_A + Y_B) ~ X, data = .x)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach, using the new `pivot` functions from the latest release of `tidyr`...

```
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols=-X, 
                           names_to = c(".value", "Class"), 
                           names_sep = "_") %>% 
  group_by(Class, rank) %>% 
  summarise(Reg = list(lm(Y ~ X)))
```

This creates a tibble with columns `Class`, `rank`, and the list output `Reg` of the `lm` model for `Y~X` for each combination.  You can then `map` through it to extract the summary, coefficients, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `map2` for corresponding 'group_by` and dependent columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
map2(c('rank_A', 'rank_B'), c("Y_A", "Y_B"), ~ {
           grp <- .x
           predCol <- .y     
           newCol <- str_replace(predCol, "Y", "Reg") 
          df %>%
                group_by_at(grp) %>% 
                nest %>%
                 mutate(!! newCol:= map(data,
                     ~lm(reformulate('X', response = predCol))))
    }
   )
```

Comment: Thanks! but this only considered `rank_A`. Once I have my regression for `rank_A` I want to `group_by(rank_B)` and perform the regressions again. i.e. regress `Y_A` on `X` for `rank_A` and then regress `Y_B` on `X` for `rank_B`.

Comment: @user113156  Is it for corresponding columns? i.e. `rank_A` for `Y_A` and `rand_B` grouped for `Y_B`

Comment: @user113156  Thank you for the comments.  I initially though about the 'ranks' but then I was thinking that both should be based on the same group.  Updated the post